Double jump script not subtracting 1 from initial jump
Can't figure out where I'm going wrong on this one. If I set max jumps to 1, I get a double jump, and when I set it to 0, I get no jumps.
For some reason, on the initial jump, the value isn't decreasing by 1.
I've tried a couple of other ways as well with no luck
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour
{
    public float moveSpeed = 8f;         
    public float jumpForce = 20f;        
    public Transform groundCheck;        
    public LayerMask groundLayer;        
    public float coyoteTime = 0.2f;      
    public int maxJumps = 2;             

    private Rigidbody2D rb;
    private bool isGrounded;
    private float coyoteTimeCounter;
    private int jumpCount;

    void Start()
    {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // horizontal movement
        float moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

        // ground
        isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.1f, groundLayer);

        // Coyote Time
        if (isGrounded)
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
            jumpCount = maxJumps; 
        }
        else
        {
            coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
        }

        // Handle Jumping
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
        {
            if ((isGrounded || coyoteTimeCounter > 0f) && jumpCount > 0)
            {
                
                PerformJump();
            }
            else if (jumpCount > 0)
            {
                
                PerformJump();
            }
        }

        
        Debug.Log("Jumps left: " + jumpCount);
    }

    void PerformJump()
    {
        rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
        jumpCount--; 
        coyoteTimeCounter = 0f; 
    }
}


At a guess: isGrounded is still true on the next execution of Update.

There's a few refactors you can do to make it a bit less confusing to read
        if ((isGrounded || coyoteTimeCounter > 0f) && jumpCount > 0)
        {
            
            PerformJump();
        }
        else if (jumpCount > 0)
        {
            
            PerformJump();
        }

the first if block changes nothing, you can simplify to just
        if (jumpCount > 0)
        {
            
            PerformJump();
        } 

and the only way your jumpCount can be getting reset (assuming there's no other code you're not sharing) is if isGrounded is true. Maybe your distance isn't changing by enough units in one tick, leading that grounded jump reset to always trigger (as ProgrammingLlama suggested)? Could you use vertical velocity to determine isGrounded? Or start a timer on the first jump to force ignore isGrounded till the player actually leaves the ground?

I can't comment to get more information but this may be the reason why it is causing the double jump.
For starters, the answer given by The Lemon is likely correct that having two if statements doing the same thing isn't helping. If you do what they propose of having a single if statement checking if you have a jumpCount higher than 0.
Another reason is that the isGrounded check contains a physics circle large enough that the following frame is still touching the ground. Causing your jumpCount variable to restart to the maximum. The solution here is to either reduce the size of the physics circle or increase the rate/speed at which the player jumps. I recommend reducing the circle size as it helps reduce the risk that it hits a nearby wall or object with the ground tag and restarts your jumpCount value.

Thanks guys, got it sorted with your help.
Simplified the if statement and changed the logic of the jumps to be additive (not including the initial jump)
public class PlayerMovement : MonoBehaviour

public float moveSpeed = 8f;         
public float jumpForce = 20f;       
public Transform groundCheck;      
public LayerMask groundLayer;        
public float coyoteTime = 0.08f;      
public int extraJumps = 0;             

private Rigidbody2D rb;
private bool isGrounded;
private float coyoteTimeCounter;
private int remainingJumps;

void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
}

void Update()
{
    // horizontal movement
    float moveInput = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(moveInput * moveSpeed, rb.velocity.y);

  
    isGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.1f, groundLayer);

    // Coyote time
    if (isGrounded)
    {
        coyoteTimeCounter = coyoteTime;
        remainingJumps = extraJumps; 
    }
    else
    {
        coyoteTimeCounter -= Time.deltaTime;
    }

    // Handle jumping
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Jump"))
    {
        if (coyoteTimeCounter > 0f || remainingJumps > 0)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector2(rb.velocity.x, jumpForce);
            coyoteTimeCounter = 0f; 
            remainingJumps--; 

            

        }

    }
}

}
